# How to create a template for a custom URI associated with the user

Tags: users, page-template, user-meta

I am working on a site where I am using a plugin called [Favorite Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/favorite-post/) so logged-in users can add a post (a custom post type) to their favorites.

I created a page called `my-favorites` which allows the logged-in user to see the posts he has favorited.

Now I need to create a page which allows the another user or visitor to check this user's favorites.

So I need to be able to do three things:

1. Get a function related to author that returns a link like
   `example.com/user/username` which I can append to /favorites to get
   the link - `example.com/user/username/favorites` (`the_author_link()` and `get_the_author()` link seems to link to the website and `the_author_posts_url()` outputs the a tag with the name. any function to just get the url or maybe modify author to show user instead?)
2. Get WordPress to use a template called `favorites.php` to display this
   page. (If the structure matches, then how do I tell WordPress which template to use?)
3. Get the user id of the user in order to show his/her favorites to
   the visitor. Right now, I use the `[favorite-post]` shortcode in my
   template file and can pass a parameter called

   ```
   [favorite-post user_id = ""]
   ```

   Will it automatically get the user id if the page is branched out from /author?

I found this [article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite/) but it still deals with custom post types and `query_vars` which I am not using. How do I make it work for the favorites page? Most other similar questions asked here were solved using a slug for the custom post type or taxonomy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you ned a function (template tag) to display the url. You can write a custom function that output the url in the format you want, however, putting the username in a public url can be a security issue.

The function can handle the link and accept an argument `$user` that can be a user id or a user object. If non is passed, the function will try to use current post author (if in the loop).

```
function get_user_favorites_url( $user = NULL ) {
  if ( is_int($user) ) $user = new WP_User( $user );
  if ( ! $user instanceof WP_User ) $user = get_the_author();
  if ( $user instanceof WP_User && $user->exists() ) {
    return home_url( 'user/' . $user->user_login . '/favorites' );
  }
}
```

Now you have to make WordPress understand this kind of urls. You have to use a rewrite rule for the purpose.

You said in OP that you are not using query vars, but you should. The problem is that once you want to use a pretty permalink, you have to use a rewrite rule, and any parameter added via a rewrite rule is only accessible via query var and not via `$_GET`.

So:

```
function user_favorites_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'user/([^/]+)/favorites', 'index.php?favorites=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'user_favorites_rule', 1 );

function user_favorites_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'favorites';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'user_favorites_var' );
```

After adding this code, go in your backend, visit the page "*Settings -> Permalinks*" to flush rewite rules.

Now you have an url format, and when you visit that url WordPress will set a query variable 'favorites' filling it with the required username.

However, we wont WordPress load the 'favorites' page when we call that url.

What I suggest you is to create a custom page template, and assign the page "My favorites" to it.

So create a new php file, name it `'page-favorites.php'`, and inside it write only this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Favorites
*/
require( 'favorites.php' );
```

Nothing else.

Now, in the backend, create a page (if you don't have it already), and assign to it the template just created.

After that, we can use 'pre_get_posts' to query this page when the user favorites url is used.

```
function user_favorites_noquery( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_home() ) return;
  $user = $query->get('favorites');
  if ( ! empty($user) ) {
    $mq = array(
      'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'page-favorites.php'
    );
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array($mq) );           
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
    $query->query['favorites'] = NULL;
    $query->query_vars['favorites'] = NULL;
    user_favorites_get_user( $user );
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'user_favorites_template', 9999 );
    // following line is to prevent WordPress redirect to the page standard url
    remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'user_favorites_noquery' );

function user_favorites_get_user( $user = NULL ) {
  static $the_user = NULL;
  if ( ! empty($user)  ) $the_user = $user;
  return $the_user;
}

function user_favorites_template() {
  return get_template_directory() . '/favorites.php';
}
```

With this code, we tell WordPress to call first page with the template `'page-favorites.php'` when the favorites url is required.

The function `user_favorites_get_user` is an helper function we use to save the required user, avoiding the use of global variables.

The function `user_favorites_template` force WordPress to load 'favorites.php' as template.

Inside `'favorites.php'` the relevant part is to output the shorcode for user favorites posts.

There are 2 possibilities: an user is logged and want to see own favorites posts, or someone (logged in or not) want to see the posts favorited by an user.

That can be *translated* in code like this:

```
//favorites.php

$user_required = user_favorites_get_user();
$user = FALSE;
if ( ! empty($user_required ) ) {
  $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_required );
} elseif ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
}
if ( $user instanceof WP_User && $user->exists() ) {
  echo do_shortcode( '[favorite-post user_id = "' . $user->ID . '"]' );
} else {
  echo 'No user selected.';
}
```

Now, when a user is logged in, he/she can visit the url `example.com/my-favorites` (if 'my-favorites' is the slug of the page assigned to "My Favorites" page template) to see his/her own posts.

Any logged or not logged visitor, can use an url like `example.com/user/username/favorites` and vieving the favorites post for that specific user.

Comment: Works like a charm! It took me two whole hours to figure out what you've written and am still not sure I understand all of it (my OOP knowledge is a bit poor) but thanks a ton for taking the time to explain as much.